# How to easily integrate a series of images in pdf with audio using Mac Os X

Tags: audio, mac

I made a lesson and would like to put it on the web. I have the audio recording of it. I also have the slides. I made them using Keynote, and then can export them to pdf.

I now need to integrate the two so I make a video with the slides as the visual part and the audio as the auditory part.

Usually I do the following:
open the audio in Audacity. Go through the whole audio cutting the pauses, the repetition, ...
Then with the cleaned audio, open iShowU HD, start recording, open the first slide, run the audio, move the slides along, stop recording. I then cut the first few seconds and store that.

This is very complicated, and what's worse it is very unforgiving. If half way I make a mess with the slide movement or I speak, I need to start again.

I need some other program where I can insert the audio, the slides, and he just records at what time to move on. ANd then I can go and change the number of seconds after which it mad e a slide change. Without starting again.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...Why dont you use Imovie, or final cut, you could bring in your .pdf (may need to convert to jpg) but then put them full screen to the music...really simply stuff

Comment: The problem is how to sync the speech with the slides. It is easy to upload the slides, as a series of jpg on iMovie. And upload the audio too. But then I have to go through each slide and set the time. Having a 100 slides this is long. Plus when I change a slide at the beginning this ofsets all the time. It's obvious iMovies wasn't made for this kind of work. Maybe Final Cut, would be better, but it's 300$!

Comment: @PietroSperoni I think going through all the slides is unavoidable.

Comment: Well, how you go through them is the issue. WHat in one tool is really long (iMovies) is simpler in another (iShowU HD). But then with iShowU HD I cannot change the final result. Or, if I change the length of one slide this extra time is taken from the next slide or it slides them all? In any case I have decided to buy FCP. As I have several video to edit I know it will pay off. Thanks